# use fncychap for only some chapters

Tags: fncychap

I am going to use `fncychap` package. Since I am creating each chapter separately and then put them together, this package works on table of contents too. Is there any way to do not work for this part?

Comment: Off-topic comment: Please accept the answers to your other questions first before you pile up questions. Otherwise this looks like if you don't care about the efforts of other users here wanting to help you.